# error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null

Tags: java, exception, null, numbers

I got this error when i try to run my code:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at edu.ndhu.bm.healthow.HealThowConstant.<init>(HealThowConstant.java:91)
at edu.ndhu.bm.healthow.HealThow.main(HealThow.java:511)
```

i have searched for similiar answer but i still couldn't fix it. This must be something related to the conversion of data types but i do not know how to fix the problem.
I am new to Java programming so any help will be much appreciated. Thank you. and here's the code:

```
package edu.ndhu.bm.healthow;

import java.util.Properties;

public class HealThowConstant
{
  public final int n;
  public final int m;
  public final int d;
  public final int t;

  public final double taux;
  public final double etax;
  public final double ax;
  public final double bx;
  public final double alphax;
  public final double betax;
  public final double qx;
  public final double add_taux;
  public final double tauUpperBoundx;
  public final double lux;
  public final double minlux;
  public final double gux;
  public final double mingux;

  public final double tauy;
  public final double etay;
  public final double ay;
  public final double by;
  public final double alphay;
  public final double betay;
  public final double qy;
  public final double add_tauy;
  public final double tauUpperBoundy;
  public final double luy;
  public final double minluy;
  public final double guy;
  public final double minguy;

  public final double tauw;
  public final double etaw;
  public final double aw;
  public final double bw;
  public final double alphaw;
  public final double betaw;
  public final double qw;
  public final double add_tauw;
  public final double tauUpperBoundw;
  public final double luw;
  public final double minluw;
  public final double guw;
  public final double minguw;

  public final String nfetay;

  public final int ant;
  public final int iteration;

  public final String parameter;

  public final int fl;
  public final int fu;
  public final int pl;
  public final int pu;
  public final int cl;
  public final int cu;
  public final int rl;
  public final int ru;
  public final int Cl;
  public final int Cu;
  public final int ul;
  public final int uu;
  public final int al;
  public final int au;

  public final String scenario_generate;

  public final int scenario;
  public final int average;
  public final int variance;

  public final int stage;

  public final double runtime;

  public HealThowConstant(Properties properties)

  {
  n = Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty("n"));
  m = Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty("m"));
  d = Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty("d"));
  t = Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty("t"));

  taux = Double.parseDouble(properties.getProperty("taux"));
  etax = Double.parseDouble(properties.getProperty("etax"));
  ax = Double.parseDouble(properties.getProperty("ax"));
  bx = Double.parseDouble(properties.getProperty("bx"));
  alphax = Double.parseDouble(properties.getProperty("alphax"));
  betax = Double.parseDouble(properties.getProperty("betax"));
  qx = Double.parseDouble(properties.getProperty("qx"));
  add_taux = Double.parseDouble(properties.getProperty("add_taux"));
  tauUpperBoundx = Double.parseDouble(properties.getProperty("tauUpperBoundx"));
  lux = Double.parseDouble(properties.getProperty("lux"));
  minlux = Double.parseDouble(properties.getProperty("minlux"));
  gux = Double.parseDouble(properties.getProperty("gux"));
  mingux = Double.parseDouble(properties.getProperty("mingux"));

  tauy = Double.parseDouble(properties.getProperty("tauy"));
  etay = Double.parseDouble(properties.getProperty("etay"));
  ay = Double.parseDouble(properties.getProperty("ay"));
  by = Double.parseDouble(properties.getProperty("by"));
  alphay = Double.parseDouble(properties.getProperty("alphay"));
  betay = Double.parseDouble(properties.getProperty("betay"));
  qy = Double.parseDouble(properties.getProperty("qy"));
  add_tauy = Double.parseDouble(properties.getProperty("add_tauy"));
  tauUpperBoundy = Double.parseDouble(properties.getProperty("tauUpperBoundy"));
  luy = Double.parseDouble(properties.getProperty("luy"));
  minluy = Double.parseDouble(properties.getProperty("minluy"));
  guy = Double.parseDouble(properties.getProperty("guy"));
  minguy = Double.parseDouble(properties.getProperty("minguy"));

  tauw = Double.parseDouble(properties.getProperty("tauw"));
  etaw = Double.parseDouble(properties.getProperty("etaw"));
  aw = Double.parseDouble(properties.getProperty("aw"));
  bw = Double.parseDouble(properties.getProperty("bw"));
  alphaw = Double.parseDouble(properties.getProperty("alphaw"));
  betaw = Double.parseDouble(properties.getProperty("betaw"));
  qw = Double.parseDouble(properties.getProperty("qw"));
  add_tauw = Double.parseDouble(properties.getProperty("add_tauw"));
  tauUpperBoundw = Double.parseDouble(properties.getProperty("tauUpperBoundw"));
  luw = Double.parseDouble(properties.getProperty("luw"));
  minluw = Double.parseDouble(properties.getProperty("minluw"));
  guw = Double.parseDouble(properties.getProperty("guw"));
  minguw = Double.parseDouble(properties.getProperty("minguw"));

  nfetay = properties.getProperty("nofactoryetay");

  ant = Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty("ant"));
  iteration = Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty("iteration"));

  parameter = properties.getProperty("parameter");

  fl = Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty("fl"));
  fu = Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty("fu"));
  pl = Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty("pl"));
  pu = Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty("pu"));
  rl = Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty("rl"));
  cl = Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty("cl"));
  cu = Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty("cu"));
  ru = Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty("ru"));
  Cl = Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty("Cl"));
  Cu = Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty("Cu"));
  ul = Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty("ul"));
  uu = Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty("uu"));
  al = Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty("al"));
  au = Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty("au"));

  scenario_generate = properties.getProperty("scenario_generate");

  scenario = Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty("scenario"));
  average = Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty("average"));
  variance = Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty("variance"));

  stage = Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty("stage"));

  runtime = Double.parseDouble(properties.getProperty("runtime"));
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please show us the properties file too?

Comment: What line is `HealThowConstant.java:91`? One of your `properties.getProperty` is returning a `null` that is being passed into `Integer.parseInt`.

Comment: @MikeKobit this is the line 't = Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty("t"));' so how's that? why only that 'properties.getProperty' is returning a 'null' while other is not?

Answer (score 3):

This stack trace is saying that on line 91, you are using `Integer.parseInt` but you are passing in `null` into it.  That is why this error is happening.  You must pass in a `String` that represents an integer.  You can't pass in `null`.

You either need to check for null and avoid passing it in, or make sure that line 91 always passes in non-null.

Answer (score 0):

As [Daniel Kaplan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28074330/627727) said, you are passing in a `null` value into `Integer.parseInt` which is causing the exception. The Javadoc for `parseInt` says that this will cause a `NumberFormatException` to be thrown:

> **Throws**:
>
> `NumberFormatException` - if the string does not contain a parsable integer

As you said in your comment, this is happening at `t = Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty("t"));` The problem is that your `properties` variable is called and cannot find a property. Looking at the Javadoc for the [`java.util.Properties`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) method `public String getProperty(String key)`, emphasis mine:

> Searches for the property with the specified key in this property
>   list. If the key is not found in this property list, the default
>   property list, and its defaults, recursively, are then checked. **The
>   method returns `null` if the property is not found.**

It seems like you want to avoid passing in a `null` to the `Integer.parseInt` method. You can do this is in different ways depending on how you want to model your class, but here are a few that you could do:

1. Do a `null` check before you do `Integer.parseInt`
2. Use the `public String getProperty(String key, String defaultValue)`, that supplies a default if a property cannot be found. I.e., `properties.getProperty("t", "15")`